# JSF get immediate attribute value java program

Tags: jsf, immediate-attribute

Can any one tell me how I can get the immediate attribute value from Java code ?
I tried to the attribute in both the ways as below: My project is in jsf 1.2

```
        <h:inputText value="" immediate="true">
            <f:attribute name="immediate" value="true"/>
            <f:attribute name="testAttribute" value="true"/>
        </h:inputText>
```

I can see the 'testAttribute' in attributes Map but not the 'immediate' attribute.

```
          if (UIComponentBase.getAttributes().containsKey("immediate")) {
              this.immediate = (Boolean)comp.getAttributes().get("immediate");
          }
```

The getAttributes() return an attributes map which does not have 'immediate' as an entry.
Please suggest another way to read the value of an immediate attribute.

Comment: I think changing the attribute name `immediate` to another name should solve the problem, because it's reserved key word.

Comment: Yeah. other attributes are retrieved fine. But I want to know if the component has immediate or not. I'm checking as below:

Comment: if (component instanceof EditableValueHolder) {
 EditableValueHolder holder = (EditableValueHolder) target;
 this.immediate = holder.isImmediate();
} else if (component instanceof ActionSource) {
 ActionSource action = (ActionSource) target;
 this.immediate = action.isImmediate();
}